# Running out of HTTP requests with a Ajax function on my server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, timeout, httprequest

I don't know so much about servers and HTTP requests limits, in my case I have a Linux Deluxe hosting on GoDaddy, which runs pretty smoothly, but now I would need to understand why my website goes unreachable (`ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`) after launching the following code 2-3 times (the first time it goes fine, the issue comes when I refresh the page 1-2 other times):

My ajax call:

```
function XSGetPointer(id, tableName) {
        var pointer;
        var ok = false;

        $.ajax({
            url : TABLES_PATH + 'm-query.php?',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'tableName=' + tableName,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var results = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
                    if (results[i]['ID_id'] == id ) {
                        pointer = results[i];
                        ok = true;
                    }
                    if (i == results.length-1 && !ok) {
                        pointer = null;
                    }
                }
            // error
            }, error: function(e) { 
                console.log('XSCurrentUser -> Something went wrong: ' + e.message);
        }});
    return pointer;
    }
```

PHP for loop where that JS script gets called:

```
for(var i=0; i<objectsArray.length; i++){
    var userPointer = XSGetPointer(objectsArray[i]['PO_userPointer_Users'], 'Users');
    $('#queryData').append(
         '<p>'
        +userPointer['ST_username']+
        '<br></p>'
    );
}// ./ For • Show results
```

The `for` loop above iterates through 57 items (the `objectsArray's` length). The `m-query.php` script simply gets all data from a JSON file, like this:

```
// Get JSON data
$data = file_get_contents($tableName. '.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);
echo json_encode(array_values($data_array), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The support from GoDaddy told me to get a VPS server, but I couldn't understand the real cause of my issue, I suppose is something related to the many HTTP requests I send in the same page, as shown here:

[image: Chrome Network panel]

As you can see, my ajax call stops after a few calls, it doesn't get to 57, and the Chrome Console shows:

```
jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST https://example.com/m-query.php? net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I just wanted to know if switching to a VPS server may fix this issue, or if my ajax query is just totally wrong since it's also `async: false` (I cannot make it `true`, because it doesn't get JSON data then).

Comment: You need to check server logs to understand what is happening, without it will be as good as any guess.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my dumb question, but how do I check server logs?

Comment: @FrankDev Are you able to sort the same?  I am facing similar issue with AJAX.

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same issue. did you get a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved the issue by simply moving my php files into an AWS Lightsail instance